# A matrix is similar to its transpose without jordan form

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, transpose

> Let $A \in M_{n×n}\mathbb{(C)}$ be invertible. Then
>
> $(A^∗)^{−1} = (A^{−1})^∗$
>
> Let B be a nonsingular matrix such that $A = B^{−1}B^∗$ . Show that $A^{−1}$ is similar to $A^∗$. ($A^*$ is complex conjugate transpose).

I have already shown the first part by showing that $A^*(A^{-1})^*$ is same as $(A^{-1}A)^*$ which is identity.

Now for second part I showed that $A^{-1}$ is transpose of $A^*$. How to show that transpose of two matrix are similar without using the jordan form.

Comment: Sorry for asking. I did it already. But if someone can help me show the proof of last statement, I will be very thankful.

Comment: *"Now for second part I showed that $A^{−1}$ is transpose of $A^\ast$."* No, it isn't. E.g.$$B=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}\ \Rightarrow\ A=B^{-1}B^\ast=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&1}\ \Rightarrow\ A^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&0},\ A^\ast=\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&1}\ne(A^{-1})^T.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply use the definition of $A$ in terms of $B$.

If you have $A=B^{-1}B^*$, then 
$$A^{-1}=B^{-*}B, \quad A^*=BB^{-*}.$$ 
So 
$$A^{-1}=B^{-*}B=B^{-1}BB^{-*}B=B^{-1}A^*B$$ 
and hence $A^{-1}$ and $A^*$ are similar.